# Is a function that reads a line onto s and returns its length good practice?

Tags: c, function

K & R section 1.9 code for saving the longest line of an input has the function:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) 
{

    int c, i;

    for(i = 0; i < lim -1 && (c =getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = c;
    return i;
}
```

Yet, for best practice, I've learned that a function only does one thing. I believe this function copies the line in its input onto the char array of s AND returns the length. Is this not considered two things? Would I be correct in my assumption that this is a bad practice?

To elaborate, we do use the input from the getLine function but in a very non-intuitive way.

```
main() 
{
    int len;    /*current line length*/
    int max;    /*Current max line length seen so far*/
    char line[MAXLINE]; /*Current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /*Longest line saved here*/

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) 
        if (len > max) {
             max = len;
             copy(longest, line);
        }

    if (max > 0)             /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}


/*FUNCTION GETLINE TAKEN OUT */


/*copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */

void copy(char to[], char from[]) 
{
    int i;

    i = 0;

    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;

}
```

Comment: Even if you consider reading line of text and returning it's length two separate things, I would say that separating it just for the sake of good practice would be very impractical.

Comment: @j_kubik I'm asking if you consider the function to be doing two things and if so, is it impractical to have good practice in C? Or possibly, is C an exception to the rule?

Comment: `printf` prints a string and returns the number of characters it wrote. As long as this `getline` *already* keeps a count of the string length, why not return it as a result? It even returns `0` for "no input".

Comment: @Jongware For me it is confusing doing two things at once. I would much rather make a function that grabs the input and copies it to a char array and make another function to return its length. I just have to understand if it is just me or is this actually a better idea.

Comment: Aren't there a couple of errors in your "sample use"? Why test `> 80`? `max` never gets updated; surely the indentation of the `if` is misleading, or it needs braces?

Comment: @Jongware, the indentation is wrong (read misleading) but the code is correct.

Comment: @Luis: but `max` is *tested* but never *changed* from 0!

Comment: @Jongware yup you're right about that part of the code, I was just referring to the getline function exclusively.

Comment: Somehow, I grabbed the code that was edited a bit to increase my understanding of what was happening. The sample code is now from the book. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for two reasons.

First one could argue that the purpose of `getline` (as the name suggests) is to read a line from input. The fact that it also returns the number of characters read could be explained by the way C-strings work and that the function could otherwise not be used to read data containing null-bytes.

Second the function does not contain any additional code to calculate the length. It is a byproduct of reading the string. The function would otherwise be of type `void` so there are really no drawbacks to returning the length of the string.

Also coding guidelines are not and end unto themselves but should help producing good code. I do not see how this code could possibly improve by omitting the return statement and writing a separate *O(n)* function to retrieve the length.

Answer (score 2):

The `getline()` function is not doing two separate things. It's doing two very closely related things, and it's definitely not bad practice to have it return the string's length.

**Do not try to fit functions, algorithms and other similar things into schemas blindly.** What `getline()` does is conceptually correct, since **a string is an object.** It has a contents buffer **and** a length. Both "properties" belong to the string object, and in fact, I would consider it bad practice to separate them.

Also, it would be unnecessarily complicated (and inefficient) to have yet another function that computes the string length. In C, strings are 0-terminated and thus such a function has to walk the entire string in order to find its length.

(Not to mention that there already is such a function in the C standard library, it's called `strlen()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Often for strings, and in general arrays, this is not an exception but actually very useful behavior. In a sense, arrays have an implicit length property. Sometimes this is known at compile time, sometimes it is known at runtime and stored in a variable and sometimes it can only be determined by virtue of being a null-terminated array.

In any case, since one cannot return an array by value, returning the length of the array (which is often very handy to know) is a very useful property of functions that write an array into a buffer. I might even argue it is idiomatic in C when the written array's length cannot be known by the caller.

ADDITION:
The above answer is with respect to functions that do not allocate memory but only write into a provided buffer. It's sometimes useful to return a simple struct `struct { size_t size; valtype* vals; }` if knowing the allocated array size is always useful to the caller and you don't want to later iterate over the array. Drawing the parallels with your question, you can see why in a way it isn't really doing two things; it's just giving you a more complete result.